# Error creating new form elements in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I get this error when trying to create a new form element:

> Declaration of Phalcon\Forms\FileUpload::render() must be compatible with that of Phalcon\Forms\ElementInterface::render()

This is my code:

```
namespace Phalcon\Forms;

class FileUpload extends Element implements ElementInterface
{
    public function  __construct(string $name, $options, array $attributes)
    {

    }

    public function render(array $attributes)
    {
        return 'my form element html'; 
    }
}
```

I have tried every different notation of parameters at this point but I still receive the same error.

So I am wondering if it is possible at all to create form elements like this in Phalcon, or if it's just something I missed in the documentation.

http://phalcon.agent-j.ru/en/1.3.0/Phalcon/Forms/Element/
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Forms_ElementInterface.html

I am using version 1.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the phalcon documentation this protoytype is defined:

```
abstract public string render (array $attributes=?);
```

So i changed my code to this:

```
public function render($attributes = false)
{
    return 'my form element html'; 
}
```

i was just not familiar with the =? notation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Phalcon 2 right?! In this version signatures should be followed more strictly. I've too got a bunch of errors like this one when I switched to Phalcon 2 but thankfully this version is written Zephir that makes the source code easier to read.

As you can see in the [**ElementInterface**](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/2.0.0/phalcon/forms/elementinterface.zep) definition, the signatures aren't much consistent yet but we can easily see that `render()` has just one parameter without the `array` type hint. Just remove the `array` type from your interface implementation to match the current signature.

Comment: It turns out i overlooked something, thank you for your time. I posted my findings.